# XCode 12.5 Missing entitlement com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-appclips

After I updated Xcode version to 12.5 I have problem with App Clip.

During App Store Connect uploading I receive warning:

`TMS-90876: Missing entitlement - This app contains an app clip. The entitlement 'com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers' should be present and include the value of the app clip's application identifier.`

there is no information how to add this entitlement

I tried to add 'com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers' key to entitlements file

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>{my_clip_bundle_id}</string>
</array>
```

but the error appears

`Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: {my_bundle_id}" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers entitlement.`

Comment: The entitlement should be auto-generated. This is what I did: [guide](https://github.com/aheze/AppClipQuickStart)

Comment: It was, and it worked until Xcode 12.5.
I see in your example there are no signs of com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers
But did you try upload app to TestFlight ? Warning appears only after upload is finished

Comment: Interesting... some other people are [also getting the same problem](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/676064). Could be an Xcode 12.5 bug.

Comment: I am getting the same problem suddenly yesterday in xcode 12.5 despite a release working a week or so ago. We do not have an app clip, nor did we try to add one so this is rather mysterious.

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I still not able to use app clip

Answer (score 9):

This seems to be a bug on Apple's side.

All you need to do is regenerate the provisioning profiles.

If you are using `Automatically Manage Signing`, there is a way to trick `XCode` to create a new profile for you. Go to Project Target > `Signing & Capabilities` page and add a new `Capability` (for example `Sign in with Apple`). This will force the regeneration of the provisioning profile. After that, you can remove the newly added Capability and upload a new build without any warnings.

Comment: In my case it's not working, even though I've just regenerated the provisioning profile it's complaining about it doesn't contain that entitlement. Am I missing something?

Comment: After lots of tries, this is the only solution working for me, thanks~

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution for me

Answer (score 6):

I was facing same issue. I was missing `$(AppIdentifierPrefix)`.

adding below to .entitlement file of main app fixed for me.

```
<key>com.apple.developer.associated-appclip-app-identifiers</key>
<array>
     <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.app.appclipbundleid</string>
</array>
```